# Kendo UI jquery grid multiple cell selection event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI jQuery grid functioning properly. I need to detect when the user drags to select multiple cells (see image), but not finding any built-in event handlers.

[image: Screen shot of grid]

...I'm specifically looking for the event where the user finishes dragging, if available.

Comment: The change event is the closest I think you can get. But that only fires upon release, not whilst drag selection is still being made: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events
Maybe that's enough, since you can still tell if multiple cells were selected?

Comment: That event will work well enough, thank you.